# I'm not getting an answer. Complement of a base 10 integer(LC-1009)

Tags: c++

```
//25. complement of a base 10 integer **important**
int n,answer=0;
cout<<"enter a number:";
cin>>n;
int m=~n;
int i=0;
while(n!=0){
    int bit=n&1;
    answer=(bit*pow(10,i))+answer;
    n>>1;
    i++;
}
int mask=0;
int j=1;
while(j<=i){
    mask=(mask<<1)|1;
    j++;
}
answer=mask&m;
cout<<answer;
```

I wrote a code to get an integer value like for `5` ie `101` in binary I should get `010` that corresponds to `010` that corresponds `2`, but it's not going that way.

Comment: Well, that code doesn't even compile?

Comment: Do you mean 2's complement? or 1's? Because the 2's complement of **101** is **011**.

Comment: Also be careful using `pow()` in combination with integers. The results of that function aren't exact.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796422/why-the-output-is-110-not-111

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it compiled but there was no error and no answer as well

Comment: @digito_evo 1s complement

Comment: @DeeZ no it doesn't: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db4995ad543c57a1

Comment: You're mask code could be simplified to something like `mask = (1 << i) - 1`.

Comment: Don't use `pow` for integer arithmetic it may not give you the results you are expecting (second time I've said this this morning). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796422/why-the-output-is-110-not-111)

Comment: To be clear, you are complementing _only_ the _significant digits_ on the input `n`. Because the actual complement of `int` 5 is not 2 but -6.  You need to provide a more rigourous specification of requirements. Even with that "complication" you have rather made this over complicated I think.

Comment: @DeeZ Please post complete code, that includes the `main` function. It might seem pedantic, but it's not hard to do. I've seen literally thousands of cases here where someone left out the code they didn't think was important and it turned out the error is in the code they left out.

Comment: Regarding avoidance of `pow`, here simply start with `p = 1` and perform `p *= 10` on each iteration.  Your method is an example of "over-complication".

Comment: @DeeZ Instead of using `pow` you should be building up a **string** of digits that contains the result you want. This is easier and more reliable than the method you are using above, which is basically creating a fake base two number in your `answer` variable.

Comment: @Clifford It's even easier to forget about numbers and realise that you can get the result you want with strings.

Comment: @deeZ, what would you like the answer to be (as an int) for n = 0 and for n = 1, 3, 7, 15, 31? Should your function be reversible?

Comment: ```return n ^ ( 2 * bit_floor( n ) - 1 );```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend representing 2 as ten. You'll loose out on much of the range. If you need to keep the leading 0s, do the operations on a string, otherwise there's the `~` operator: `int n = 5;
    auto asStr = std::format("{:b}", n);
    for (auto& c : asStr)
    {
        c = ('1' + '0') - c;
    }
    std::cout << asStr << '\n';`

Comment: ... and what about negative numbers? Which I assume you allow since you chose to use `int` rather then `unsigned`?  Far too much ambiguity.

Comment: @john Perhaps.  I was referring only to the use of pow to produces series 1,10,100... in general - the use of such a series in this case is another issue.  Thinking even more holistically, the transformation as a whole can be far simpler - with no strings.

Comment: `n>>1;` does not change n.

Answer (score 2):

The problem as presented is highly ambiguous, and any "complement" ought to be reversible (which this isn't). However, within the constraints of the Leetcode problem from which this seems to be taken (and requiring C++20) the following code should solve it.

**EDIT: EXPLANATION**: Suppose you have an integer n. Then the (ahem) "complement" is precisely that which fills in the interlacing 0s. For example:

```
Original n:  101001
Complement:  010110
```

If you add these together you will get (with precisely no carries):

```
             111111
```

So the "complement" is the "all ones" minus the original number.

You can get the "all ones" in the usual way by starting with the next power of two and subtracting 1. No overflow will occur here because converting from an `int` to an `unsigned` leaves room to multiply by 2.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <bit>              // requires C++20
using namespace std;

int complement( int n ){ return n ? 2 * bit_floor( unsigned(n) ) - 1 - n : 1; }

int main()
{
   for ( int n = 0; n < 32; n++ ) cout << n << " ----> " << complement( n ) << '\n';
}
```

Output (spot the pattern?):

```
0 ----> 1
1 ----> 0
2 ----> 1
3 ----> 0
4 ----> 3
5 ----> 2
6 ----> 1
7 ----> 0
8 ----> 7
9 ----> 6
10 ----> 5
11 ----> 4
12 ----> 3
13 ----> 2
14 ----> 1
15 ----> 0
16 ----> 15
17 ----> 14
18 ----> 13
19 ----> 12
20 ----> 11
21 ----> 10
22 ----> 9
23 ----> 8
24 ----> 7
25 ----> 6
26 ----> 5
27 ----> 4
28 ----> 3
29 ----> 2
30 ----> 1
31 ----> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for the example you have provided.  It does not resolve the ambiguity over zero or negative values (which all result in zero).

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 0 ;
    cout << "enter a number:" ;
    cin >> n ;
    
    // Create mask of significant binary digits of n
    int bits = 0 ;
    for( unsigned a = n; a != 0;  a >>= 1, bits++ ) {}
    unsigned mask = ~(~0 << bits) ;
    
    // Complement and mask n
    int answer = (~n) & mask ;
    
    cout << answer ;

    return 0;
}
```

If it is required that 0 -> 1, then treat it as a special case:

```cpp
    unsigned mask = (bits == 0) ? 1u : ~(~0 << bits) ;
```